# passing data to a controller using service

Tags: angularjs

On the code below, I am trying to reference the `photos` array in the `appService` service from the `pictureCtrl` controller, but it won't work well. The only thing that works is `$scope.photoService` referencing `appService` when I try to call the model on the HTML. When I try to call `currentPhoto` model on the HTML it won't show anything.

I would like to get the `currentPhoto` model on the HTML page referencing the first index of the `photos` array which will be an object and when I click on the favorite button on HTML it will run the `sendFeedback` method and will change `currentphoto`. How can do it?

```
.controller('pictureCtrl', function ($scope, appService) {
  // angular.extend($scope, appService);
  $scope.photoService = appService;

  $scope.photos = appService.photos;

  $scope.currentPhoto = appService.photos[0];

  $scope.sendFeedback = function (bool) {
    if(bool) {}//add it to favorite

    var randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * flickrData.photos.length-1);
    $scope.currentPhoto = angular.copy($scope.service.flickrData.photos[randomIndex]);
  };


})

.factory('appService', function ($http) {

  var photoService = {};
  photoService.photos = [];
  photoService.feelingText = "";

  photoService.getFlickrPictures = function (text) {
    console.log('this has been called');
    return $http({
      method: "JSONP",
      url: apiUrl+'&text='+text+'&format=json&jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK'
    }).then(function (data) {
      photoService.photos = data.data.photos.photo;
      console.log('flickrData', photoService.photos);
    }, function(err){
      throw err;
    });
  };

  return photoService;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the photos array never has been populated. Since you are using a factory, the thing that will get injected into your controller will be a fresh instance of photoService.

You will only see photos if you first call your function to fetch the data from the $http service.

I would create a function loadPhotos on your service that would return the data as a promise to your controller.

Comment: Thanks. that helped. in the meantime, I created a event listener on the controller and broadcast event on the service so it will be triggered when getFlickrPictures method is called. the controller now gets the data once the event happens.